# ggplot2 stacked area-bar plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, stacked-area-chart

Is there a way to combine stacked bar plot and stacked area plot in ggplot2 (or in any other graphics package in R)? I'd like to create a stacked bar plot with some space between the columns. The groups of the bars should than be connected by the areas. In other words, instead of edges of an area plot, there should be bars with percentage labels for the groups.

What I've tried is:

```
ggplot(subdata, aes(x=variable, y=value, group=Name, fill=Name)) +
geom_area (positon="fill") +
geom_bar(stat="identity", colour="black")
```

The problem is that I'd like the filled areas to connect the boundaries of the bars rather than their midlines. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what you are looking for. I know it's kinda out of the ordinary, but [this guy made a really good illustration demostating what he was looking for](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596113/stacked-barplot-together-with-line-in-r) which in turn lead to some good answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked this question on the `ggplot2` mailing list after not getting any answers here, and  Winston Chang came up with a solution: [Thread within ggplot2 google group](http://groups.google.com/group/ggplot2/browse_thread/thread/594d6d321da7043e/47dfa68bcfc94953?lnk=gst&q=combination%20of%20stacked%20area%20plot%20and%20stacked%20bar%20plot#47dfa68bcfc94953)

Comment: You should consider recognizing this as an complete answer and close this thread.

Comment: Could you reproduce the answer here?